# OneDrive not syncing files with illegal character in filename

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive

OneDrive is not syncing multiple files with an illegal character in their filename. The character is a black dot symbol.

Screenshot of an example as I can't copy/paste the dot into text!

[image]

Can someone please help me with removing this character in a quick manner?

I ran a PowerShell script that successfully removed ! & { } ~ # % " characters, but this dot has me stumped!

I believe these files originated from a Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]"
$mystring -replace $Pattern
```

for more information see here: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/06/weekend-scripter-remove-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string/

regex cheatsheet: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran the following command but no luck, no files were renamed. I believe I am close. Can you please help?   Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$','' }

Comment: Sorry i did a typo in the regex. It should be: `-replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$]'` note the `^` character. I've updated my post above. Alternatively you can also just use the regex `'[\W]'` to get the opposite of word characters. You also don't need the second blank parameter in the -replace statement. I've also update this in the answer above.

Comment: I noticed another typo in my regex... I've simplified it and tested it working. Code I used was: `Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\test" | Rename-Item -Path {$_.FullName} -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]' }` Your code should look like: `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]' } ` or `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[\W]' } `. Up to you which to use. `\s` is whitespace

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the Unicode characters using PowerShell. [Refer here](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2015/08/powershell-remove-special-characters.html)

Example
`$String -replace '[^\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A]+', ''`

You can look up for the Unicode of the character online.